# Evaluate the limit as x approaches zero of $(\sin(a+2x) -2\sin(a+x) + \sin a )/ x^2$

Tags: calculus

I reallyyyy need help with this question!
Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(a+2x)-2\sin(a+x)+\sin(a)}{x^2}$$
I know the answer is $-\sin(a)$ but I don't know how to get it!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with l'Hospital? Or Taylor series?

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\sin A+\sin B$? Use it to combine first and last term in numerator.

Comment: Hey! My teacher hasn't taught us L'Hopital's rule or Taylor series!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

- $\sin (A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A$

then we have

$$\sin(a+2x)-2\sin(a+x)+\sin(a)=$$

$$\sin a\cos(2x)+\cos a\sin (2x)-2\sin a \cos x-2\cos a\sin x+\sin(a)=$$

$$=\sin a-2\sin a \sin^2x+2\sin x\cos x\cos a-2\sin a \cos x-2\cos a\sin x+\sin a=$$

$$=2\sin a(1-\cos x)-2\sin a \sin^2x+2\sin x\cos a(1-\cos x)$$

then

$$\frac{\sin(a+2x)-2\sin(a+x)+\sin(a)}{x^2}=$$

$$=2\sin a\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}-2\sin a \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}+2\cos a\sin x\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$$

and refer to standard limits.

Or as a shorter alternative, as suggested by Paramanand Singh, using the "*sum to product*" formula for the first and last term

- $\sin \theta + \sin \varphi = 2 \sin\left( \frac{\theta + \varphi}{2} \right) \cos\left( \frac{\theta - \varphi}{2} \right)$

we obtain

$$\sin(a+2x)-2\sin(a+x)+\sin(a)=2\sin(a+x)\cos x-2\sin (a+x)=$$

$$=2\sin(a+x)(\cos x-1)$$

then

$$\frac{\sin(a+2x)-2\sin(a+x)+\sin(a)}{x^2}=-2\sin(a+x)\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$$

Finally by l'Hopital

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(a+2x)-2\sin(a+x)+\sin(a)}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\cos(a+2x)-2\cos(a+x)}{2x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-4\sin(a+2x)+2\sin(a+x)}{2}$$

Comment: Better write the expression as $2\sin(a+x)(\cos x-1)$ by combining first and last term.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's indeed a very clever way!